# It seems I have SSH keys saved under two emails, but I can't find one of them, how can I find an SSH key that is "already imported?"

Tags: ssh, gpg, ssh-agent

I am on machine B and seeking to SSH into machine C. I failed to, which made me think perhaps I haven't actually set up my SSH keys on machine B.

If I do `ls -al ~/.ssh` on machine b, I see

```
-rw-------  1 caleb caleb 3434 Oct 14  2020 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 caleb caleb  748 Oct 14  2020 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 caleb caleb 4424 Mar 15 20:29 known_hosts
```

If i do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, I see

```
ssh-rsa {{key}} emailA@example.com
```

Ah perfect, I have `emailA` key, but I'm missing `emailB` key! I go to Machine A and run `gpg2 --export-secret-keys > secret.gpg`

I then take `secret.gpg` on a USB drive back to machine B, input it, and then do `gpg2 --import secret.gpg`

```
gpg: key C8...: "Caleb <emailB@example.com>" not changed
gpg: key C8...: secret key imported
gpg: key BA...: "calebjay <emailA@example.com>" not changed
gpg: key BA...: secret key imported
gpg: Total number processed: 2
gpg:              unchanged: 2
gpg:       secret keys read: 2
gpg:  secret keys unchanged: 2
```

Now I'm very confused. It seems I already had the key I need, `emailB` key? I don't know where to find this. I've googled where else ssh keys could be stored, and have found commands like `ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -L'`, but that just looks in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. I don't really know how `emailB@example.com` key can already imported on my machine B but not in ssh-agent.

**How can I find this apparently already existing SSH key?**